# Partial fractions integration

Tags: partial-fractions

Re-express $\dfrac{6x^5 + x^2 + x + 2}{(x^2 + 2x + 1)(2x^2 - x + 4)(x+1)}$  in terms of partial fractions and compute the indefinite integral $\dfrac{1}5{}\int f(x)dx $ using the result from the first part of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Hint

Use $$\dfrac{6x^5 + x^2 + x + 2}{(x^2 + 2x + 1)(2x^2 - x + 4)(x+1)}=\frac{A}{(x+1)^3}+\frac{B}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{C}{x+1}+\frac{Dx+E}{2x^2-x+4}+F$$
and solve for $A,B,C,D,E$ and $F$.

### Explanation

Note that this partial fraction decomposition is a case where the degree of the numerator and denominator are the same. (Just notice that the sum of the highest degree terms in the denominator is $2+2+1=5.$) This means that the typical use of partial fraction decomposition does not apply.

Furthermore, notice that $(x^2+2x+1)$ factorizes as $(x+1)^2$, which means the denominator is really $(x+1)^3(2x^2-x+4)$. This means the most basic decomposition would involve denominators of $(x+1)^3$ and $(2x^2-x+4)$. However, we can escape that by using a more complicated decomposition involving the denominators $(x+1)^3$, $(x+1)^2$, $(x+1)$, and $(2x^2-x+4)$. The $F$ term is necessary for the $6x^5$ term to arise in the multiplication, intuitively speaking.

More thoroughly stated, the $F$ term is needed because of the following equivalency between $6x^5+x^2+x+2$ and the following expression:
$$
\begin{align}
&A(2x^2-x+4)\\
+&B(2x^2-x+4)(x+1)\\
+&C(2x^2-x+4)(x+1)^2\\
+&[Dx+E](x+1)^3\\
+&F(2x^2-x+4)(x+1)^3.
\end{align}
$$

Notice how the term $F(2x^2-x+4)(x+1)^3$ is the only possible term that can give rise to $6x^5$? That is precisely why it is there.

### Hint 2

#### Part 1

In the integration of $\frac{1}{5}\int f(x)dx$, first separate the integral, $\int f(x)dx$ into many small integrals with the constants removed from the integrals. That is, $\int f(x) dx$ is
$$A\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^3}dx+B\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}dx+C\int \frac{1}{x+1}dx+D\int \frac{x}{2x^2-x+4}dx\quad+E\int \frac{1}{2x^2-x+4}dx+F\int 1dx.$$

#### Part 2

Next, use the substitution $u=x+1$ with $du=dx$ on the first three small integrals:

$$A\int \frac{1}{u^3}du+B\int \frac{1}{u^2}du+C\int \frac{1}{u}du+D\int \frac{x}{2x^2-x+4}dx+E\int \frac{1}{2x^2-x+4}dx\quad +F\int 1dx.$$

#### Part 3

To deal with the integral $\int \frac{1}{2x^2-x+4}dx$, you must complete the square. This is done as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{2x^2-x+4}dx&=\int \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{x^2-\frac{1}{2}x+2}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+\frac{31}{16}}dx.
\end{align}
$$

To conclude, you make the trig substitution $x-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{31}}{4}\tan \theta$ with $dx=\left(\frac{\sqrt{31}}{4}\tan \theta+\frac{1}{4}\right)'d\theta=\frac{\sqrt{31}}{4}\sec^2\theta  d\theta$. This gives you:

$$\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+\frac{31}{16}}dx=\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\frac{\sqrt{31}}{4}\sec^2 \theta}{\frac{31}{16}\tan^2\theta+\frac{31}{16}}d\theta.$$

Comment: The degree of the numerator and denominator is the same; so you have to do the division first. Also note $x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2$; so your factorization is incorrect.

Comment: @DavidMitra, I completely missed that. I'll correct that shortly.

Comment: @DavidMitra, I am not sure I follow "so you have to do the division first". Is it not correct to state $$\dfrac{6x^5 + x^2 + x + 2}{(x^2 + 2x + 1)(2x^2 - x + 4)(x+1)}=\frac{Ax^2+Bx+C}{(x+1)^3}+\frac{Dx+E}{2x^2-x+4}?$$

Comment: @Limitless: It's better (for many purposes) to write $$\frac{A}{(x+1)^3}+\frac{B}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{C}{(x+1)}$$

Comment: @DennisGulko, I could see why. Would it still be correct as stated above, however? Do you understand David Mitra's concern? I took "so you have to do the divison first" to imply that the denominator has some factor which is present in the numerator. This is not the case. As a result, I'm quite confused by what he said.

Comment: There is a little problem with what you wrote. The remark of @DavidMitra regards the initial fraction - there the degree of the numerator and denominator is the same, which implies that there should be some constant factor, i.e: $$\frac{A}{(x+1)^3}+\frac{B}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{C}{(x+1)}+\frac{Dx+E}{2x^2-x+4}+F$$

Comment: @Limitless Note that if you simplify the right hand side of the equation in your last comment, the degree of the numerator will be $4$ (and not $5$ as it should be). Generally, for the Partial Fraction decomposition method (as given [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/PartialFractions.aspx) for example) to succeed, the degree of the numerator must be smaller than the degree of the denominator.

Comment: @DennisGulko, all I see is that the degree of $6x^5+x^2+x+2$ and the degree of $(x+1)^3(2x^2-x+4)$ are equivalent.

Comment: @Limitless: look at my edited remark. If you expand what you wrote, you get a polynomial of degree $4$ in the numerator.

Comment: @DavidMitra, I see this now. Are you saying that partial fraction decomposition does not work due to this error? Does it work under the correction suggested by me (along with Dennis's correction)? Or are there still issues in the fact mentioned directly above, and partial fraction decomposition cannot be applied to this rational function? Oops! I misread the names. Thanks.

Comment: @Limitless The usual algorithm taught would give the wrong decomposition. However, you can correct it as Dennis writes in his comment above (in this case by adding a constant term $F$). Things will be ok then. But note the $F$ is added for this particular case. For other rational functions, a different correction term might be needed.  It would be easier, in my opinion, just to do the division (polynomial division) in these cases where the degree of the numerator is at least the degree of the denominator.